# Define a Cloudwatch alert on replication lag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Master-Slave configuration on AWS RDS MySQL.

I want to set an alert when the `replication lag` goes above a certain threshold (e.g. 10 seconds).

- How can it be done?
- If it is not possible, is there another way to achieve similar result? (without using 3rd party tools / custom scripting)

Comment: With almost any performance metric that needs to be monitored, first you create the metric and then associate an alarm to it, I don´t know if you can measure the replication lag though. one of the most advanced tool I´ve used before to monitor performance is datadoghq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can track replica lag using the [`ReplicaLag` metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/rds-metricscollected.html) on your slave instance. Note that this metric is measure in seconds. This metric is reported automatically by RDS every minute.

You can [create a CloudWatch alarm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html) to monitor the `ReplicaLag` metric. You should set this alarm to be breaching if the sum of `ReplicaLag` over an evaluation period of 1 minute is greater than 0.